# How to delete a hidden non empty folder in windows using python

Tags: python

I am making a program for myself where I want to delete a folder in windows which is stored in C:\Users\saksh_lussqvx\AppData\Local something like this. So can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using python? please help it's really important.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, best to start with some research yourself to solve the problem and provide some code attempts in your question

Answer (score 0):

import os

os.removedirs('path/to/directory')